# I encountered this while trying to install nordvpn

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, vpn

Whoops! Permission denied accessing /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock.
Run 'usermod -aG nordvpn $USER' to fix this issue and log out of OS afterwards for this to take an effect.

usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

someone help please

I tried to run this command
usermod -aG nordvpn $USER

I expected it to run successfully then when I restarted my device I would be able to log in